# 2D numpy array: remove masked elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a numpy masked array like this (where the -- is the masked data):

```
xlist = [[1000,1001,1002,--],
         [2000,2001,2002,2003]]
```

I want to create a new array where the masked data is removed, effectively returning an array like this:

```
xlist = [[1000,1001,1002],
         [2000,2001,2002,2003]]
```

I have tried this:

```
realXIndex = np.where(xlist.mask)[1]
realX = np.delete(xlist,realXIndex, axis=1)
```

This effectively removes the masked value from all subarrays, so 2003 is removed as well, while I want to maintain it.

If someone could point me into the right direction, it would help me a lot.

Comment: Be careful about where you have numpy arrays, masked arrays, and lists.  I assume the first `xlist` is a partial display of a masked array.  But what is the second one?  A list of 2 lists of differing lengths?  The `compressed` method of a masked array removes the masked elements, but returns a 1d array.  `np.delete` removes whole rows or whole columns, not selected elements.  It can't return a ragged array.

Comment: Hi.This is exactly what I encountered, and the reason why I posted this question. I was not able to get the right stuff back. Your solution worked. I discovered something like this myself couple of hours after I posted my question, but your formulation is easier to understand. I made an array of lists, which works as a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a masked array from your first `xlist`:

```
In [283]: xlist = [[1000,1001,1002,-9999],
     ...:          [2000,2001,2002,2003]]
     ...:          
In [284]: M = np.ma.masked_equal(xlist, -9999)
In [285]: M
Out[285]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[1000, 1001, 1002, --],
        [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003]],
  mask=[[False, False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False, False]],
  fill_value=-9999)
```

`compressed` removes the masked values, but returns a 1d array.

```
In [286]: M.compressed()
Out[286]: array([1000, 1001, 1002, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003])
```

We could apply compressed on a row by row basis:

```
In [287]: [m.compressed() for m in M]
Out[287]: [array([1000, 1001, 1002]), array([2000, 2001, 2002, 2003])]
```

Or as list of lists, or even object array of lists:

```
In [288]: [m.compressed().tolist() for m in M]
Out[288]: [[1000, 1001, 1002], [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003]]
In [289]: np.array(_)
Out[289]: 
array([list([1000, 1001, 1002]), list([2000, 2001, 2002, 2003])],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: The last suggestion works the best. Fast and clean :)

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that typically numpy arrays require maintaining dimensionality along all respective axis, and almost all numpy operations operate along the whole part of that axis. AKA, you can't really delete an element and make it not evenly sized.

While you can technically have mixed length arrays, they aren't operable by a majority of numpy functions.

As to your direct problem, if you want to use numpy to accomplish a lot of the work upfront and then turn it into your specific form later, you could use a fill value, then some sort of code to parse it out correctly later, from a numpy array into a normal python list.

Something like

```
masked_array = np.where(mask, xlist, -99999)
```

then

```
output = [[x for x in row where x != -99999] for row in masked_array]
```